# when assigning the unsigned char with the integer greater than 255 it gives the different output , why?

Tags: c, unsigned-char

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
   unsigned char c =292;
   printf("%d\n",c);
   return 0;
}
```

The following code gives the output "36".
I wanted to know why this happens?

Comment: Because 292 is to big.

Comment: Compile with warnings for additional hints.

Comment: print `UCHAR_MAX` on your system

Comment: The value 256 in binary is `100000000`.  It appears that the information higher than 8 bits is being thrown away, leaving 36 in the lower char bits.

Comment: unsigned char ----> 0 to 255, overflow :P

Comment: You might want to check your C language textbook about ranges of integer types.

Comment: You're evidently compiling without a useful set of warnings enabled.  Try `gcc -Wall -Wextra` for better diagnostics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The size of char data_type is 1 byte and its range is 0 to 255.
>   but here initialization is more than 255(i.e. c=292>255)
>
> Hence, c stores (292-255)th value (i.e. 37th value) and the value c stores is 36(because 0 is the first value).
>
> It means you have initialize **c = 36.**
>
> And finally, printf() func. fetch value from memory and print the value 36.

Answer (score 4):

Because 292 does not fit in a variable of type `unsigned char`.

I suggest you to compile this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main()
{
   unsigned char c =292;
   printf("%d %d\n", c, UCHAR_MAX);
   return 0;
}
```

and check the output:

```
prog.c: In function 'main':
prog.c:5:21: warning: unsigned conversion from 'int' to 'unsigned char' changes value from '292' to '36' [-Woverflow]
    unsigned char c =292;
                     ^~~
36 255
```

So, `UCHAR_MAX` in my system is 255, and that's the largest value you are allowed to assign to `c`.

292 just overflows `c`, and because it's an unsigned type, it goes from 0 to 255, thus it wraps around, giving you 292 - (255 + 1) = 36.

Comment: I think you mean `292 - (255 + 1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much @AjayBrahmakshatriya!

Answer (score 0):

When you convert 292 to binary, you will get 0001 0010 0100 (9 bits).
But unfortunately, a character variable can store only 1 byte (8 bits).
So it will take the last 8 bits. ie : 0010 0100 which is equal to 36 in decimal.
Hope this helps